# NSOperationQueue for synchronous upload

Tags: objective-c, ios, file-upload, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

Am developing an iPad application which uploads bulk of files to the server synchronously. I would like to use NSOperationQueue to add each upload request into the queue and start processing the next request after receiving the response. How this can be done?

Answer (score 2):

set maximum concurrent operation to 1 for NSOperationQueue by setMaxConcurrentOperationCount: call. In this case the queue will process next operation only if the previous one will be finished (i.e. in your case received the response).